# Join two Model classes result and display it on View-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel

I want to combine below two classes result using Linq and display the result on a view?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("ProductMaster")]
    public partial class ProductMaster
    {
        public ProductMaster()
        {
            ProductDetails = new HashSet<ProductDetail>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    }


using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class ProductDetail
    {
        public int? Price { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ManufactureBy { get; set; }


        public int? ProductId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int ProdDetailsId { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductMaster ProductMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

Join two tables data using LINQ Query.

```
 public ActionResult BindProductMasterData()
        {
           Model1 db = new Model1();
            var varResult = from pm in db.ProductMasters join pd in db.ProductDetails on pm.ProductId equals pd.ProductId select new { pm.ProductId, pm.ProductName, pd.Price, pd.ManufactureBy };
            return View(varResult.ToList());
        }
```

Display below table columns data in View
ProductId , ProductName, Price, ManufactureBy

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model for this view and assign your LINQ join query result to a list of that and pass that to the view.

```
public class ProductVm
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Name  { set;get;}
  public List<ProductDetailVm> Details { set;get;}
}
public class ProductDetailVm
{
   public int Id { set;get;}
   public int? Price { get; set; }
   public string ManufactureBy { get; set; }
}
```

and in your action method, project the result of your LINQ query to a list of ProductVm objects.

```
public ActionResult BindProductMasterData()
{
   Model1 db = new Model1();
   var varResult = db.ProductMasters
                     .Select( f =>
                new ProductVm
                {
                    Id = f.ProductId, 
                    Name = f.ProductName,
                    Details = f.ProductDetails.Select(g => new ProductDetailVm
                                                 { 
                                                   Id = g.ProdDetailsId ,
                                                   Price = g.Price,
                                                   ManufactureBy = g.ManufactureBy
                                                 }
                                       ).ToList()
                }).ToList();
  return View(varResult);
}
```

Now make sure your view is strongly typed to a list of our ProductVm view model

```
@model List<ProductVm>
@foreach(var p in Model)
{
  <h4>@p.ProductName</p>
  <p>Details</p>
  @foreach(var d in p.Details)
  {
    <p>@d.ManufacturedBy</p>
    <p>@d.Price</p>
  }
}
```